# Is W a subspace of $\mathbb{R^3}$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $W=\begin{Bmatrix}
c-6d \\ 
5d \\
3c+10d-1 
\end{Bmatrix}$ where $c,d\in\mathbb{R}$. Now I was able to find the basis which is $W=c \begin{Bmatrix}1\\0\\3 \end{Bmatrix}+d\begin{Bmatrix}-6\\5\\10\end{Bmatrix}+\begin{Bmatrix}0\\0\\-1\end{Bmatrix}$ but I'm not sure how I would go about showing that this isn't a basis for $\mathbb{R^3}$

Comment: It should be noted that with our usual addition/scalar multiplication, the *only* subspaces of $\mathbb{R}^n$ are the origin, or the lines/planes/hyperplanes which pass through the origin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:**

A subspace should be closed under addition.

Let $x$ and $y$ be elements of $W$.  You *should* have that $x+y$ is also in $W$.  Do you though?

> Let $x=\begin{bmatrix} c-6d\\5d\\3c+10d-1\end{bmatrix}$ and $y=\begin{bmatrix}e-6f\\5f\\3e+10f-1\end{bmatrix}$

---

Even easier, a subspace should contain the zero vector (the additive identity) of the space it is in.  The zero vector in $\mathbb{R}^3$ is $\begin{bmatrix}0\\0\\0\end{bmatrix}$

Is it possible that $\begin{bmatrix}c-6d\\5d\\3c+10d-1\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}0\\0\\0\end{bmatrix}$?

> If they were equal, it would imply the system $\begin{cases}c-6d=0\\5d=0\\3c+10d-1=0\end{cases}$

Comment: Another issue: subspaces should contain the origin . . .

Comment: @Noah indeed.  Was in the process of adding that.